# Is there any reason to choose __new__ over __init__ when defining a metaclass?

Tags: python, constructor, new-operator, metaclass, init

I've always set up metaclasses something like this:

```
class SomeMetaClass(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dict):
        #do stuff here
```

But I just came across a metaclass that was defined like this:

```
class SomeMetaClass(type):
    def __init__(self, name, bases, dict):
        #do stuff here
```

Is there any reason to prefer one over the other?

**Update**:  Bear in mind that I'm asking about using `__new__` and `__init__` in a metaclass.  I already understand the difference between them in another class.  But in a metaclass, I can't use `__new__` to implement caching because `__new__` is only called upon class creation in a metaclass.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

If you want to alter the attributes dict before the class is created, or change the bases tuple, you have to use `__new__`.  By the time `__init__` sees the arguments, the class object already exists.  Also, you have to use `__new__` if you want to return something other than a newly created class of the type in question.

On the other hand, by the time `__init__` runs, the class does exist.  Thus, you can do things like give a reference to the just-created class to one of its member objects.

**Edit**: changed wording to make it more clear that by "object", I mean class-object.

Comment: Much clearer.  And that makes sense.  Is there any reason to use `__init__` though?

Comment: `__new__` can do everything that `__init__` can do, but not the other way around. `__init__` can be more convenient to use though, in the same way that `__new__` and `__init__` relate in regular class instantiation. You have to remember to return something from `__new__` for example, but with `__init__` you don't.

Comment: @JasonBaker I realize this a 5 year old thread and I don't expect to get any reply. Wouldn't you want to use __init__ whenever you needed to create an instantiation of the class in question. Like with the [flyweight pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern).

Answer (score 11):

Several differences, in fact.

For one thing, the first argument in `__new__` and `__init__` are not the same, which is not made clear by everyone insisting on just using `cls` in both cases (despite the fact that the variable name doesn't hold any particular meaning).  Someone pointed this out and it's core to understanding the difference:

- `__new__` gets the **metaclass** - `MyType` in my example (remember the application-level class is not created yet).  This is where you can alter `bases` (which can cause MRO resolution errors if you're not careful).  I'll call that variable `mcls`, to differentiate it from the usual `cls` referring to application level class.
- `__init__` gets the newly-created application-level **class**, `Bar` and `Foo` and, by that time, this class's namespace has been populated, see `cls_attrib` in example below.  I'll stick to `cls` as per usual naming convention.

#### Sample code:

```
class Mixin:
    pass

class MyType(type):


    def __new__(mcls, name, bases, attrs, **kwargs):
        print("  MyType.__new__.mcls:%s" % (mcls))

        if not Mixin in bases:
            #could cause MRO resolution issues, but if you want to alter the bases
            #do it here
            bases += (Mixin,)

        #The call to super.__new__ can also modify behavior:
        #                                    classes Foo and Bar are instances of MyType
        return super(MyType, mcls).__new__(mcls, name, bases, attrs)

        #now we're back to the standard `type` 
        #doing this will neuter most of the metaclass behavior, __init__ wont
        #be called.                         
        #return super(MyType, mcls).__new__(type, name, bases, attrs)

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        print("  MyType.__init__.cls:%s." % (cls))
        
        #I can see attributes on Foo and Bar's namespaces
        print("    %s.cls_attrib:%s" % (cls.__name__, getattr(cls, "cls_attrib", None)))
        return super().__init__(name, bases, attrs)


print("\n Foo class creation:")
class Foo(metaclass=MyType):
    pass


print("\n bar class creation:")
class Bar(Foo):
    #MyType.__init__ will see this on Bar's namespace
    cls_attrib = "some class attribute"
```

#### output:

```
 Foo class creation:
  MyType.__new__.mcls:<class '__main__.test.<locals>.MyType'>
  MyType.__init__.cls:<class '__main__.test.<locals>.Foo'>.
    Foo.cls_attrib:None

 Bar class creation:
  MyType.__new__.mcls:<class '__main__.test.<locals>.MyType'>
  MyType.__init__.cls:<class '__main__.test.<locals>.Bar'>.
    Bar.cls_attrib:some class attribute
```

Answer (score 9):

You can see the full writeup in [the official docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization), but basically, `__new__` is called *before* the new object is created (for the purpose of creating it) and `__init__` is called *after* the new object is created (for the purpose of initializing it).

Using `__new__` allows tricks like object caching (always returning the same object for the same arguments rather than creating new ones) or producing objects of a different class than requested (sometimes used to return more-specific subclasses of the requested class).  Generally, unless you're doing something pretty odd, `__new__` is of limited utility.  If you don't need to invoke such trickery, stick with `__init__`.

Comment: I understand the difference between `__new__` and `__init__` for a regular class.  I was asking why I would want to use them for a metaclass.

Comment: @JasonBaker The mechanism is exactly the same. Classes are objects of their metaclasses, so their creation  works the same way.

Answer (score 2):

As has been said, if you intend to alter something like the base classes or the attributes, you’ll have to do it in `__new__`. The same is true for the `name` of the class but there seems to be a peculiarity with it. When you change `name`, it is not propagated to `__init__`, even though, for example `attr` is.

So you’ll have:

```
class Meta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attr):
        name = "A_class_named_" + name
        return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, attr)

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, attr):
        print "I am still called '" + name + "' in init"
        return super(Meta, cls).__init__(name, bases, attr)

class A(object):
    __metaclass__ = Meta

print "Now I'm", A.__name__
```

prints

```
I am still called 'A' in init
Now I'm A_class_named_A
```

This is important to know, if `__init__` calls a super metaclass which does some additional magic. In that case, one has to change the name again before calling `super.__init__`.

Comment: `__init__` gets called with the parameter `name` set to the original name, so with the same arguments as `__new__`. But `cls.__name__` should be the new one at that time.

Comment: I.e., with `print "I am still called '" + name + "' in init but have '" + cls.__name__ + "'"` you get `I am still called 'A' in init but have 'A_class_named_A'`.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement caching. `Person("Jack")` always returns a new object in the second example while you can lookup an existing instance in the first example with `__new__` (or not return anything if you want).